What do you call a mock project in developer internship?
Some IT companies offer internships where would-be developer employees build a project. It may be quite complex, involve dozens of people on the team (backend, frontend, BAs, MQAs, AQAs, PMs, POs, and so on), dailies, tracking with Jira – you name it. The key difference with "real" projects is that they don't have an actual customer who ordered it and pays for it. The key goal of such projects is to prepare underexperienced developers for actual work for an actual paying customer
What do you call such projects?
Here are some suggestions I have in mind. Even though, they may all fit semantically, I'm sure there's only one, or few "right" ways to say it (idiomatic ways)

mock project
learning project
training project
internship project


Actually, it's not true that there are only a few idiomatic options. None of these makes it perfectly clear, on its own, that the project is not for a paying client, and any of them could do so with a bit of extra explanation.

Perhaps it is a simulation of a real project. Students may expect a nice clean specification but the real world doesn't run like that. The spec might be hopeless, yet for reasons outside your control you have to get the job done. Artificial difficulties can be introduced in a controlled way to teach how to deal with them. It might be based on a previous real project, to make it easier to set up, and with a path that has already been followed.

I suspect that this is too niche to have a single well accepted term.  Different companies might call these different things, though "training project" seems to be clear enough. It doesn't say it all, but it doesn't have to.

I guess it would depend on the details, depending on what its purpose is - for training, practice, prototyping, testing, or what. In my experience most companies don't bother with complex test projects - they just expect developers to do stuff on real projects with appropriate supervision, although in some industries it may be different.

I like mock project by analogy to a mock trial - it puts emphasis on this being an exercise in following procedures and operating in a way a real project would, rather than just coding practice. It's not a common idiom, though.

I'd call it a "training project" or maybe a "practice project".
